# javascript created label inserted into wrong position

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the following html:

```
<div id="divForComponents">
       <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addFilter('divForComponents')"/>                                
</div>
```

And in my script file:

```
function addFilter(divId){
var div = document.getElementById(divId);

var label = document.createElement("label");
var text = document.createTextNode("Filter by:");
label.appendChild(text);
div.appendChild(label);

var filter = document.createElement("select");
filter.name = "selectName";
filter.options[0] = new Option("selection 1","value 1");
filter.options[1] = new Option("selection 2","value 2");
filter.options[2] = new Option("selection 3","value 3");
filter.options[3] = new Option("selection 4","value 4");
div.appendChild(filter);

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name = "inputName";
div.appendChild(input);
}
```

Now the select component and the input field are added properly, but the label is added before the button I already had on that div. I would like and expect to obtain a positioning:

```
 Button   Label   Select    Input
```

Instead I get:

```
 Label   Button   Select    Input
```

The browser I'm testing on is Chromium, not sure if that counts for anything here.

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: I don't see a button in your code.

Comment: Button is already in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it actually inserting the label before the button or just visually showing up that way?  It sounds like you may have a CSS style that is telling the label to float left.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the input. This is part of a bigger project in which I'm not usually handling the front-end so it might be that. Is there any way I could "overwrite" this?

Comment: When you create the label you could add a style attribute to the tag and put `float:none;` in the tag so that the resulting html would be something like:

Comment: Sorry comment cutoff.  I was saying something like:

<label style="float:none;">Some Text Here</label>

Not sure if your front end designers will care if you put in some inline styles though.

Answer (score 1):

For one, your function is named `addComponents()` and yet you use `addFilter()`. I've just tried your code and changed `addFilter()` to `addComponents()` and the label has been set properly.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in chrome when your function is named properly:

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/bVzwr/